# ZFS mirror with two partitions on the same disk, safe?

Tags: partitioning, zfs

I would like to create mirrored partitions on a single disk to protect against bit rot. I understand this will not protect against hardware failure.

Seeing as ZFS is intended to work with drives, could there be any problems with using partitions instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly possible although not very efficient as the disk head will seek between both disk areas for all writes.

ZFS allows to work with whole disks, primary and logical partitions and files.

Note that ZFS also support multiple data copies to help overcoming bit rot:

```
zfs set copies=2 dataset
```

Comment: Will setting the ZFS copies property will allow me to do scrubs? I suppose that would be easier on the disk than separate partitions.

Comment: Scrub will properly work in both situations. It reads all ditto blocks and it reads both sides of a mirror.